Every element realizing a nonempty type in a $\omega$-saturated model is definable
In David Marker's book, he asserts that a definable subset $X$ in a $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ is of Morley rank 0 if and only if it's finite as Lemma 6.2.7, iii).
In the proof, he assumes that $\mathcal{M}$ is $\omega$-saturated and $X$ is infinite for contradiction. Then he claims that every singleton containing distinct elements of $X$ is definable.
So here are some more details: Since $X$ is definable by some formula $\phi$ with finitely many parameters from $M$, let all these parameters form a set $A\subset M$. By Corollary 4.3.26, it is sufficient to show that every automorphism of $\mathcal{M}$ that fixes $A$ pointwise fixes $X$ pointwise.
But then I'm stuck. I wonder if it is the correct idea.

In this case, "definable" means "definable with parameters from $M$". So a finite tuple of elements $\bar{a}$ from $M$ is always definable by the formula $\bar{x} = \bar{a}$.
In the context of the definition of Morley rank, the set of parameters is not fixed. That is, in the definition of $RM(\phi) \geq \alpha+1$ (so (iii) in Marker's Definition 6.2.1), we require that $\phi(\mathcal{M})$ contains an infinite family $\psi_1(\bar{x}), \psi_2(\bar{x}), \ldots$ of $\mathcal{L}_\mathcal{M}$-definable subsets that are pairwise disjoint. Here "$\mathcal{L}_\mathcal{M}$-definable" means "with parameters from $\mathcal{M}$", but there is no requirement that these parameters are the same in all the $\psi_i(\bar{x})$.
